# All my computer files (downloads, Desktop, photos, etc) were imported to VS Code and if I delete something there, it deletes the files in my computer

Tags: node.js, react-native, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have never used VS Code before. I have taken c++ intro to CS second semester and I recently obtained an internship where I have to develop an app using React Native. I have never used the terminal in my life expect step by step tutorials from my professor to install Clion (the IDE we have used in class).
On the first day my professor just sent us some video tutorials on how to create an app with React (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-S5a0eXPoc) but my Mac is really old so I've been having to download different versions of Xcode and Node.js.  I followed the video to download VS Code.
Anyway, I got to the point where he says to open the project in VS Code and when I did, it gave me an error message. To be honest, I did so much to try to fix the error that I don't remember everything I did on my terminal, but now all my computer files/apps are in one of the projects in VS Code.

I have looked it up online and I keep seeing something about a file .git, but I don't have that file in the specific project that has all my files. To see if it deletes files from my computer, deleted a project I have in Clion (straight from VS Code) and it actually deleted my file from cLion. Someone, please help. How do I delete that entire project/ folder, which by the way has my administrator name, without deleting my original files?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by deleting a file without actually deleting it.

Comment: If I delete one of the documents in visual studio, it gets deleted from my computer too. I thought it would just delete the folder from visual studio. I’m just scared that everything in my computer now is dependent on visual studio. Hypothetically speaking, if I were to delete visual studio, would I lose all my files and apps I have installed in my hard drive? :( excuse my ignorance, again I don’t know anything other than actually using the IDE to write bad programs in c++.

Comment: No, deleting anything in Visual Studio will delete it on your computer. It's a built-in file explorer.

Comment: Is there a way to undo this if I don’t have the .git file other people have suggested in similar cases? Or do I just leave it alone and make sure I never delete visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to do here? Restore deleted files?

Comment: No, I am simply new to visual studio, and seeing how easy it is to delete any file from the app, I freaked out. I'm not worried about the cLion programs I accessed and deleted straight from VS. I just wanted to know if there was a way to not have every single file that exists on my computer, show on VS studio as a project itself. But it looks like that is normal. I thought I had changed the path of all my files to visual studio.

Comment: I've edited your post and replaced "Visual Studio" (aka VS) with "Visual Studio Code" (aka VS Code). You are not using Visual Studio, which is a completely different application - a full-featured IDE. You are using Visual Studio Code. Please, always use VS Code in your comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, will do that. I didn't know they were two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most source code/text editors, VS Code has a built-in file explorer. It works as your operating system's file manager, so if you delete something in VS Code, it's the same thing as deleting it through your system.

To be safe and, above all, organize the files you are editing, whenever you work on a project in Visual Studio Code, do the following:

File -> Open Folder -> (*Select your project folder*) -> Open

[image: select project folder]

So Visual Studio Code will only show the files in the selected folder in your file explorer, as in the example below:

[image]

If you want to have greater control to lose that fear of deleting something you shouldn't, you can use a version control system, like the [Git](https://git-scm.com/video/what-is-git) you mentioned in the comments. Git is not as complex as it seems, but I believe that in addition to its great importance, it might be better to know some things about the development environment first.

Comment: I had no idea! It would've been great to know before I started using it. Thank you so much for your advice, I will do it this way. Kinda wish I had been taught intro to CS using visual studio since it looks more involved/hands on than cLion. I feel like I'm making too many mistakes learning it on my own.

Comment: Don't worry so much about that kind of thing, when it comes to development, especially mobile development you'll notice that technologies do a lot more than you need, so try to start with the basics. Any doubts create a question here, it's a great habit.